# Segmentation fault with structure containing arrays

Tags: arrays, structure

My program needs to read the values (integers and floats) from the input file. There are many values in one line, separated by tabs, and there are many lines in the file. I have planned to read the whole file line-by-line, parsing each line and storing the whole content into the structure which consists of two-dimensional static arrays. Then, when the whole thing is stored in memory, I would do calculations, fill the results out into another structure, and at the end dump the content of that structure into the output file. Of course it doesn't work, I get segmentation fault error when trying to run the program.

This is how I define the input structure:

```
#define sim_spectrum_constant 122
#define real_spectrum_constant 181
#define num_days 365

  struct spectrum {
    int year[sim_spectrum_constant][num_days];
    int month[sim_spectrum_constant][num_days];
    int day[sim_spectrum_constant][num_days];
    int hour[sim_spectrum_constant][num_days];
    int minute[sim_spectrum_constant][num_days];
    int second[sim_spectrum_constant][num_days];
    float wavelength[sim_spectrum_constant][num_days];
    float irr_total[sim_spectrum_constant][num_days];
    float irr_direct[sim_spectrum_constant][num_days];
    float irr_diffuse[sim_spectrum_constant][num_days];
  };

  struct spectrum pS;
```

This is how I initialize the arrays:

```
// initialization
  for (i=0; i<sim_spectrum_constant; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<num_days; i++) {
      pS.year[i][j] = 0;
      pS.month[i][j] = 0;
      pS.day[i][j] = 0;
      pS.hour[i][j] = 0;
      pS.minute[i][j] = 0;
      pS.second[i][j] = 0;
      pS.wavelength[i][j] = 0.;
      pS.irr_total[i][j] = 0.;
      pS.irr_direct[i][j] = 0.;
      pS.irr_diffuse[i][j] = 0.;
    }
  }
```

And this is how I read in the values from the input file:

```
// determining how many simulated spectrums are provided in the file + reading spectrums into the array
  row = 0;
  n = 0;
  if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), pInput_spektrum) == NULL) {
    printf ("****Simulated spectrum doesn't contain any entries!! -- %s\nPress <enter> to exit...\n", strerror(errno));
    getchar();
    exit(-1);
  }

  while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), pInput_spektrum) != NULL) {
    result=sscanf(line, "%i %i %i %i %i %i %f %f %f %f", pS.year[row][n], pS.month[row][n], pS.day[row][n], pS.hour[row][n], pS.minute[row][n], pS.second[row][n], pS.wavelength[row][n], pS.irr_total[row][n], pS.irr_direct[row][n], pS.irr_diffuse[row][n]);
    row ++;
    if (row == sim_spectrum_constant) {
      n ++;
      last_row = row;
      row = 0;
    } 
  }
```

Am I failing in the idea, implementation, or both? What causes the segmentation fault?

Thanks!

Comment: Are those arrays initialized somewhere?

Comment: No, is it obligatory? This is my first C program in a decade, sorry :(

Comment: I just added initialization and recompiled, still the same issue, it seems. I have updated the above with how init was done.

Comment: Could you debug to know which line the error arises?

Comment: I did try, however the debug never runs through the program. I just get the warning message, almost immediately, that "An Access Violation (Segmentation Fault) [was] raised in the program". Debug doesn't seem to be able to go through the program after that. I have also tried to set control printfs throughout the program, printing incrremental numbers every couple of lines, in order to be able to locate where the issue is more precisely. However when I run the program, not even the first printout is seen -- which means that the program practically doesn't start at all?

Comment: after every printf(...) use fflush(stdout).

Comment: OK I do have something strange. I thought that the program doesn't execute at all. However, when I add breakpoints very early, debug mode does reach them. As soon as I add the breakpoint one row after the "int main  (void) {", the segmenation fault warning is returned and the whole thing gets blocked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not evaluate what `sscanf` returns, it returns the number of arguments it has parsed so that would be a useful thing to check. Normally checking return values is a *good thing*

Also if you have fixed arrays with fix dimensions then you should also check borders like n not becoming too large. `n>=num_days` input data tend to surprise us programmers quite often - in a bad way.

your struct seems overly complex, the idea with a struct is to make things simpler and more organized but you treat it as some kind of monolith variable where you dump everything. you should consider having more structs inside that one like for instance the date could be one struct and the members starting with `irr_xxx` seems also like a likely candidate for a struct.

e.g.

```
struct irr
{
  float total;
  float direct;
  float diffuse;
};
```

Comment: The problem is solved! Segmentation fault was caused by the fact that the arrays are quite big, and stack could not accomodate them. 

I first tried to change the linker parameters to increase the stack available, however that didn't help.

Then I redefined my structures like this:
__static__ struct spectrum pS;

... and segmentation fault was gone.

I am also taking into account the other advices provided here, which for sure will make my program design much better.

Thanks to everyone who was helping!

Regards